# How to open PowerPoint file in resource file C#

Tags: c#

I have a number of small `PowerPoint` files in my resources folder and I want to open them. I'm having issues doing this as my `Resource.sendToPPTTemp` is of type `byte[]` and to open the file I need it as a string. Is there a way I can open a file from resources as a string?

```
var file = Resources.sendToPPTTemp;
ppnt.Application ppntApplication = new ppnt.Application();
var _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

var myppnt = ppntApplication.Presentations.Open(file.ToString());
ppntApplication.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

Comment: No. Powerpoint is an application, not a library. It opens *files*. You must provide a file to it, eg by saving the buffer to a temporary file

Comment: Why did you store a presentation in a resource anyway? What are you trying to do? Why not just deploy the file with your application?

Comment: I have a number of PowerPoint files I need to open and I didn't want to be giving them all string paths.

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? How would that be easier than what you do now?  If you don't want to hard-code file names, store them as settings or string resources

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the path to your file to the `Open` method, not the binary representation. Either you have the path and pass it to the method or you have to create a file with your byte[].

I'd rather create a folder with all your PPT and store in your resource file the path to that folder. Then you can use the first method:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(Resources.PPTFolderPath);
foreach(var file in di.GetFiles())
{
    var myppnt = ppntApplication.Presentations.Open(fi.FullName);
    ppntApplication.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    [..]
}
```

But if you really want to store your PPT in the resource file, you can do it like this, with a temporary file for example:

```
var tmpPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
try
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(tmpPath, Resources.sendToPPTTemp);

    var myppnt = ppntApplication.Presentations.Open(tmpPath);
    ppntApplication.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    [..]
}
finally
{
    // you have to delete your tmp file at the end!!!
    // probably not the better way to do it because I guess the program does not block on Open.
    // Better store the file path into a list and delete later.
    var fi = new FileInfo(tmpPath);
    fi.Delete();
}
```